# How to stop an animation in Java?

Tags: java, animation

I need to know how to stop an object in Java Graphics from moving after the Thread starts. The animation is done by changing the properties of the indicated shape. I tried to put a condition on `run()` to make the object stop moving but it seems like it did not go through the condition.

This is the code for the object I will animate.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.geom.*; 
public class House implements DrawingObject
{
    private double x;
    private double y; 
    private Color roofC;
    private Color baseC; 
    private Triangle roof; 
    private Square base; 
    private double speed; 
    private double size; 
    public House(double a, double b, Color r, Color ba, double sz)
    {
        x = a; 
        y = b; 
        roofC = r; 
        baseC = ba; 
        size = sz;
        roof = new Triangle(x, y, x + (size / 2), y + (size / 3), x - (size / 2), y + (size / 3), roofC); 
        base = new Square(x - (size / 2), y + (size / 3), size, baseC); 
        speed = -5; 
    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x; 
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        speed = 0; 
    }
    //these are the methods to be overridden when implementing DrawingObject
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, AffineTransform at)
    {
        roof.draw(g2d, affn); 
        base.draw(g2d, affn); 
    }

    public void animate()
    {
        roof.incX(speed); 
        base.incX(speed);
    }
```

And this is the code where I draw the object and call its `animate()` method.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.geom.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode; 

public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent implements Runnable
{
    private int width; 
    private int height; 
    private JFrame frame; 
    private boolean running; 
    private int delay; 
    private ArrayList<DrawingObject> dos = new ArrayList<DrawingObject>(); 
    private MyKeyListener mkl; 
    private Graphics2D g2d; 

    private House h; 

    public DrawingComponent(JFrame f)
    {
        frame = f; 
        running = false; 
        delay = 100; 
        h = new House(640, 200, Color.RED, Color.WHITE, 100); 
    }

    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 

        AffineTransform reset = g2d.getTransform();

        RenderingHints rh = 
            new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);




        //move to 250, 200
        h.draw(g2d, reset); 
        dos.add(h); 
    }

    public void activateKL()
    {
        mkl = new MyKeyListener(); 
        frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(mkl); 
        frame.getContentPane().setFocusable(true); 
    }

    class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener 
    {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(DrawingComponent.this);
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        { 
            if(!running)
            {
                running = true; 
                t1.start(); 
            }
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        { 
            if(!running)
            {
                running = true; 
                t1.start(); 
            }

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
        }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        while(running)
        {
            animateAll();  
            repaint(); 
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(delay); 
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
            }
            if(h.getX() <= 250)
            {
                h.stop(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public void animateAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dos.size(); i++)
        {
            dos.get(i).animate(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In the `DrawingComponent` method, there is an ArrayList of `DrawingObject`s that supposedly has all the objects with that implementation. `animateAll()` calls out all the animations for each `DrawingObject` in the ArrayList.

So I used a method here to change to stop the House object from moving, yet it still does not work. I even tried putting the conditional `if(h.getX() <= 250)` inside the `House` class, and even in the `animateAll()` class. Am I missing something in my code?

PS: It is required that I do the program like this, so suggestions such as using Timers or removing the `animateAll()` method will not be approved.

PS 2: I'm not sure if there is an answer to this already, but I've already checked other answered but none of them has solved my problem.

Comment: Seems you are working in separate threads without taking care of concurrency issues. Read about the Java memory model. It seems at the very least some of your variables need to be `volatile`.

Comment: What is the point of calling `dos.add(h)` when `h` never changes?  (You should never modify state in a paintComponent method, by the way;  the system controls how often paintComponent is invoked, and you have no control over it.)